# window.location.hash scroll down isn't smooth only scroll left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've implemented a scroll left for navigating to sections that works perfectly.
Now I want to add anchors within a section so if you click on them they scroll down on a page to other anchors, smoothly. I'm trying to add the functionality within my existing function but to no avail.

I'm using "jquery.easing.pack.js".

In the original one I have the HTML and JS looks like this:

```
<!-- scroll left to sections -->
<section id="1" class="section"></section>
<section id="2" class="section"></section>
<section id="3" class="section"></section>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        var $sections = $('section.section');

        $sections.each(function() {
            var $section = $(this);
            var hash = '#' + this.id;

            $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').click(function(event) {
                $scrollElement.stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $section.offset().left
                }, 1200, 'easeOutCubic', function() {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Now I have:

```
<!-- scroll left to sections -->
<section id="1" class="section">
    <a class="scroll-down" href="#bottom-div">scroll down</a><!-- scroll down to div -->
<div id="bottom-div>here we go</div>
</section>
<section id="2" class="section"></section>
<section id="3" class="section"></section>
```

At the moment if I click on the "scroll down" anchor it will go to the `bottom-div` but not smoothly. So I've tried adding another function like this but it's not working.. any ideas how to make it work and if possible with my existing function?

```
$(function() {
            var $bottomdivs = $('.scroll-down');

            $bottomdivs.each(function() {
                var $bottomdiv = $(this);
                var hash = '#' + this.id;

                $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').click(function(event) {
                    $scrollElement.stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $bottomdiv.offset().top-100
                    }, 1200, 'easeOutCubic', function() {
                        window.location.hash = hash;
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: A fiddle would describe it clearly.

Comment: @John: Looks pretty straightforward to me, as in the way I have described it, although feel free to provide a solution, edits or ask me any questions should you not understand my original post.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the hash I think you are invoking the standard anchor link functionality to jump to the section. Try handling the scroll yourself like this:

```
var $sections = $('section.section');

$sections.each(function() {
    var $section = $(this);
    var hash = '#' + this.id;

    $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').click(function(event) {

        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollLeft: $section.offset().left
        }, {queue:false, duration: 1200, easing: 'swing'});

        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $section.offset().top
        }, {queue:false, duration: 1200, easing: 'swing', done: function () {
            window.location.hash = hash;
            }
        });

    });

    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have put together a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/rjE4s/

I am not sure what $scrollElement was so I have removed that from my example. Also I have changed your custom easing as I didn't have the easing pack installed. You can just change that back. Finally, I queued the animations so the left and top scroll at the same time, but you just set:

```
queue: true
```

in the animation options and it will animate the left and then the top like in your original function. Not sure if you wanted this or not.

Comment: Thanks @DoubleA but not quite what I was after. The sections are linked to from a header nav and that scrolls the page left and right accordingly. What I'm interested in is adding to my original function so that if you are on a section and then want to smooth scroll down to an anchor within the section, it will do it. The animate left and top will never happen at the same time, they are two separate clicks for the user. For `$scrollElement`, `var scrollElement = 'html, body',
        $scrollElement;`

Comment: Oh I see. You could still use this same method - I have updated the fiddle so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/rjE4s/1/